# I want to store images for my website

Tags: image

I am developing one website.I want to store images.Users are supposed to insert images with their post.What are methods to store images?Is storing images in database really reliable?I thought about the amazon AWS but it's not reliable.

Comment: Possible duplicate question [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In today's web world, storing images in the DB or locally on your disks are not becoming good options as they were one day.

I usually prefer the separation of concerns concept, which means each part of the application should do one thing and do it very well, and this is becoming so important now when talking about scalability, maintainability, and fault tolerance.

Now, regarding your question: Im interested to know, how Amazon is not reliable for storing images? I'm asking this because Amazon S3 (and similar) is becoming the defecto-standard method for storage nowadays.

In my opinion, you can go with Amazon storage, or better off pick one of the image storage services like [Cloudinary](http://www.cloudinary.com) or [File Picker](http://filepicker.com), which offer more than image storage solutions, with the possibility to backup your images on Amazon S3 and similar services, you can have them checked.

Comment: I don't doubt the AWS.At this point i don't want to invest anything.Amazon s3 offering 20,000 get request and 2000 put request.But one of my friend said after crossing the limit they start deducting money from your credit card automatically.Is it true?

Comment: Yes, If you exceed the free limit quota, they will cost you money. But same thing will happened when you start growing your database in the hosting company, in addition to not being a good practice

Comment: so what should i do? I checked the Cloudinary they are offering 75000 images.

Comment: Go for it, they have a nice free starter plan and a nice admin page

Comment: If you think your question has been answered, please check my answer as the correct one